# What does this zenity mean when it says "Couldn't connect to accessibility bus"?

Tags: lubuntu, xrandr, zenity

Context: Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty), 3.19.0-26-generic (#28~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 12 14:09:17 UTC 2015), Xorg 1.17.1 (13 May 2015  04:35:05AM), Toshiba Satellite L750

I am trying to write a script to control the brightness of my screen.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
BRIGHTNESS=`zenity --scale --text="Dim screen" --min-value=1 --max-value=9 --step-value=1 --value=9`
#xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 0.$BRIGHTNESS
```

(xrandr is deliberately commented out at this point.)

I had initially thought zenity would work with floating point numbers so I had `--min-value` as `0.0` and `--max-value` of `2.0` and a `--step-value`  of `0.1`. I got an error (the same as I'm getting now) so I changed to integers and changed the `xrandr --brightness` value to `0.$BRIGHTNESS`.

It doesn't seem to matter what I do. I get the following error:

```
bugmagnet@bugmagnet-Satellite-L750:~/bin$ ./brightness

** (zenity:6095): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-3jrfy88FSO: Connection refused
This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.
```

I'm fairly sure that my syntax is okay. So where am I going wrong?

Comment: The second error (*"option is not available"*) appears to be because the step parameter is just `--step` rather than `--step-value`: see `zenity --help-scale`.

Comment: @steeldriver can you post that as a solution so that you can get some kudos. I thought I had RTFM but in this case obviously not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second error ("option is not available") appears to be because the step parameter is just `--step` rather than `--step-value`:

```
$ zenity --help-scale
Usage:
  zenity [OPTION...]
```

Scale options
  --scale                                           Display scale dialogue
  --text=TEXT                                       Set the dialogue text
  --value=VALUE                                     Set initial value
  --min-value=VALUE                                 Set minimum value
  --max-value=VALUE                                 Set maximum value
  **--step=VALUE                                      Set step size**
  --print-partial                                   Print partial values
  --hide-value                                      Hide value

i.e.

```
zenity --scale --text="Dim screen" --min-value=1 --max-value=9 --step=1 --value=9
```

I don't know what is causing the accessibility bus warning: however there are some possibly related bug reports [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/at-spi2-core/+bug/1193236) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1326099).